# Previous Month MTD

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there anyways I can find Previous month's MTD?
So my data is at day level and I need to find MTD and previous month MTD

```
D_date               product    TOTAL_UNIT
01/AUG/2020            A         10
01/AUG/2020            B         20
02/AUG/2020            A         15
02/AUG/2020            B         25
29/JUL/2020            A          5
29/JUL/2020            B          0
30/JUL/2020            A          2
31/JUL/2020            B         30
```

I can get current month MTD using below SQL (Oracle)

```
SUM(TOTAL_UNIT)OVER( PARTITION BY PRODUCT, TRUNC(D_DATE,'MM') ORDER BY D_DATE )MTD
```

However, when I do add_months -1 to get PMTD, it still shows the current MTD

I tried doing

```
SUM(TOTAL_UNIT)OVER( PARTITION BY PRODUCT, TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(D_DATE,-1),'MM') ORDER BY D_DATE )MTD
```

Another way I can find is by doing a self-join but I would like to avoid that for performance issues.

Comment: The tag you've added does not provide any information. Please [edit] to remove it, add a tag for the specific DBMS you're using, and a [mre] that we can use to help solve your problem.

Comment: Can you share expected result for this data set.

Comment: What is "MTD" and "PMTD"?

Comment: @Scratte MTD Is month to date and PMTD is previous month Month to date.

Comment: expected output will be: @mohdatif
MTD for today :
                                            MTD                   PMTD
10/AUG/2020            A         25                         7
10/AUG/2020            B         45                         30

Comment: You should add clarifications to your Question with an edit. Not only in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Changing your partition-by clause to `TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(D_DATE,-1),'MM')` - or `ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(D_DATE,'MM'),-1)` - gives you a different *value* for that partitioning bu exactly the same groups as plain `TRUNC(D_DATE,'MM')`.

If you want to get the last MTD before the current month you can put your existing query as a subquery and use `lag()`:

```
select d_date, product, total_unit, m_date, mtd,
  last_value(mtd) over (partition by product order by m_date range between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as prev_mtd
from (
  select d_date, product, total_unit,
    TRUNC(D_DATE,'MM') m_date,
    SUM(TOTAL_UNIT)OVER( PARTITION BY PRODUCT, TRUNC(D_DATE,'MM') ORDER BY D_DATE )MTD
  from your_table
)
order by product, d_date;
```

```
D_DATE    | PRODUCT | TOTAL_UNIT | M_DATE    | MTD | PREV_MTD
:-------- | :------ | ---------: | :-------- | --: | -------:
29-JUL-20 | A       |          5 | 01-JUL-20 |   5 |     null
30-JUL-20 | A       |          2 | 01-JUL-20 |   7 |     null
01-AUG-20 | A       |         10 | 01-AUG-20 |  10 |        7
02-AUG-20 | A       |         15 | 01-AUG-20 |  25 |        7
29-JUL-20 | B       |          0 | 01-JUL-20 |   0 |     null
31-JUL-20 | B       |         30 | 01-JUL-20 |  30 |     null
01-AUG-20 | B       |         20 | 01-AUG-20 |  20 |       30
02-AUG-20 | B       |         25 | 01-AUG-20 |  45 |       30
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=99ac9aa20c1fda9b41c021ef01ecc716)

Comment: This does Help. Thanks for the help. However, I cannot use a subquery as that will reduces my performance terribly due to size of the data. I was hoping for some analytical functions that can be used.

Comment: This is using analytic functions; and only hits the table once. Those functions have some overhead of course, but why does using a subquery in this form (an inline view) affect performance? Have you actually tested and seen a big performance impact - over the entire data set, not just the first block of rows returned - or are you guessing/assuming it will happen?

Answer (score 0):

That is because you're using add_months inside an analytic function. So what you are doing is calculate the sum, partitioned by the month, as if it were the previous month.. While the last part doesn't make much sense to me, it does give you the correct SUM, but you didn't tell SQL to show the the previous month as well.

If you want the D_DATE to be showed as previous month, add another column `trunc( ADD_MONTHS( d_date, -1), 'MM') as pmtd`

```
select trunc( ADD_MONTHS( sysdate, -1), 'MM') from dual;
```

This will always get you the first date of the previous month.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I want to show the sum of previous month as on current date. So not sure adding a new column with the previous date would be helpful??